# "censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result" }

Tags: jenkins, ansible, jenkins-pipeline, ansible-inventory

I am using ansible with jenkins pipeline and facing the above issue
and I just ran into the situation that converging my role failed with

TASK [postgresql-data-update : Ensure PostgreSQL users are present.] ***********
fatal:  FAILED! => {
"censored": "the output has been hidden due to the fact that 'no_log: true' was specified for this result"
}

Comment: And what is your question? Yes, indeed, when your task have a `no_log: true` then your output will be hidden so a password won't actually leak in the output or error message.